# Find Mac OS X version number in objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

How can I find the version number of Mac OS X (eg. "10.6.7") from my Cocoa Objective-C application?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157759/how-can-i-determine-the-running-mac-os-x-version-programmatically

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I determine the OS version at runtime in OS X or iOS (without using Gestalt)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072804/how-do-i-determine-the-os-version-at-runtime-in-os-x-or-ios-without-using-gesta)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
#import <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>

SInt32 major, minor, bugfix;
Gestalt(gestaltSystemVersionMajor, &major);
Gestalt(gestaltSystemVersionMinor, &minor);
Gestalt(gestaltSystemVersionBugFix, &bugfix);

NSString *systemVersion = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.%d.%d",
    major, minor, bugfix];
```

Comment: Be aware that this code is deprecated.  Recommend checking in the linked article.

Comment: @Brett According to David Smith aka Catfish_Man, an engineer at Apple, it is fine to use Gestalt for version numbers. See [his tweet](https://twitter.com/Catfish_Man/status/373277120408997889).

Comment: Bavarious that is interesting, but it just goes to show that Apple's right hand doesn't always know what the left is doing.  Code shouldn't be marked deprecated unless it is...

Comment: @Bavarious What if we want the actual name of the OSX e.g LION etc. Thank you

Answer (score 19):

You could use the same technique that Apple's code uses...

```
NSDictionary *systemVersionDictionary =
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:
        @"/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist"];

NSString *systemVersion =
    [systemVersionDictionary objectForKey:@"ProductVersion"];
```

Apple does exactly this to fill in the version number for various system utilities in the function `_CFCopySystemVersionDictionary` here:

http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744/CFUtilities.c

Comment: Will this work on a sandboxed app, though? IMHO always better to use the system APIs..

Answer (score 12):

For OS X 10.10+ I think using `NSProcessInfo` is an easier and safer way to do that:

```
NSOperatingSystemVersion version = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersion];
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld.%ld.%ld", version.majorVersion, version.minorVersion, version.patchVersion]);
```

Comment: The `operatingSystemVersion` method is new with OS X 10.10, so it didn't exist when the earlier answers were written.