# How do I Determine the Current Version of macOS Using PowerShell 6.x or Newer?

Tags: macos, powershell, powershell-core

Using a PowerShell script in PowerShell 6.x or newer, running on macOS, how do I programmatically determine the version number of macOS?

Edit:
Maybe something like this answer, plus string-parsing?:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/157784/2134110

Comment: Why would you run, or even install PowerShell on a Mac please? It already has extremely competent shells and tools installed.

Comment: I'm writing a systems inventory tool in PowerShell that is cross-platform with Windows.

Comment: I see, thanks for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way:

```
sw_vers -productVersion

10.12.6
```

Or do something with

```
system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType -xml
```

like:

```
[xml]$xml = system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType -xml   
$xml.plist.array.dict.array.dict.string -match 'macos'  

macOS 10.12.6 (16G1510)
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks. If you want to amend your answer, this worked well for me:
$versionMacOS = [version](sw_vers -productVersion)